# Unable to login to phpmyadmin with the root user

Tags: server, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a `root` user in `mysql-server` on the Ubuntu server. I am unable to login to phpMyAdmin with the `root` user and password. I was trying to find the configuration file but could not locate it. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

You have to reconfigure phpMyAdmin, reset MySQL password:

1. Reconfigure phpMyAdmin
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch terminal
3. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`
4. Connection method for MySQL database for phpmyadmin: `unix socket`
5. Name of the database's administrative user: `root`
6. Password of the database's administrative user: `mysqlsamplepassword` (change this to your desired MySQL password)
7. MySQL username for phpmyadmin: `root`
8. MySQL database name for phpmyadmin: `phpmyadmin`
9. Web server to reconfigure automatically: `apache2`
10. `ERROR 1045`
11. Ignore
12. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`
13. New password for the MySQL "root" user: `mysqlsamplepassword` (use the same password as in step 6)
14. Repeat password for the MySQL "root" user: `mysqlsamplepassword` (use the same password as in steps 6 and 13)

Comment: After 5 years this reply helped me.
I skipped steps 12,13 and 14
(raspbian lamp configuration)

Answer (score 16):

I encountered a similar problem in Ubuntu 14.04 using MariaDB. Instead of trying to change everything I just created a new user.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Entered the root password
Created a new user using the following command:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_very_complex_password';
```

Granted all permissions to newuser:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can then log on using newuser in phpMyadmin. I would strongly encourage you to only grant specific privileges to newuser instead of Carte Blanche privileges but it's your own funeral.

Comment: I had the same problem with my Raspberry Pi. I was about to complain that it was giving me the same access denied error when I remembered sudo. Thank you for this shorter workaround

Answer (score 8):

To log in as root in phpmyadmin:

```
echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin = 'unix_socket';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" | mysql -u root -p
```

Found at the end of [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-lamp-on-debian-stretch/)

Worked for me :)

Comment: Thank you for actually posting the answer to this question, unlike the other replies.

Comment: sudo bash before the above stuff for some ubuntu based distros ;)

Comment: this is the ONLY solution that worked for me. i tried everything, this is the only. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

By "rootuser" you mean the MySQL root user, not the system root user, right?

During the installation of `mysql-server`, the MySQL root account is created and its password is stored in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

The configuration files of phpMyAdmin are stored in `/etc/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Yes, I mean MySQL root user and not the system root user.I found the config file. Why is phpmyadmin not allowing to log me in with the mysql user login

Comment: @user14010: Does the command-line `mysql` version work? E.g. `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p` ?

Comment: Yes it works. I am able to login to mysql through command line version but not with phpmyadmin. The reason why I am trying to use phpmyadmin is I have a sql script when I am trying to import it using the commandline mysql it is creating problems with the foreignkeys resulting in error 121. When I import the same script uing phpmyadmin it succesfully creates the tables

Comment: @user14010: What error message did you get? I've updated my answer with the location of the PMA configuration files.

Comment: I had to use **debian-sys-maint** user to login in phpmyadmin, for some reason mysql root user cannot login in phpmyadmin. **debian-sys-maint** has the rights to create databases, create users, grant privileges, etc., so it can be used for administrative tasks.  **debian-sys-maint** credentials are generated automatically when installing mysql-server and are saved in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

Answer (score 3):

Might for some reason the *AllowRoot* option be set to False? See the [documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_AllowRoot).

Answer (score 3):

I installed MySQL using synaptic manager. Didn't have to enter a root password.
The command:

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

worked. I was able to login into PhpMyAdmin immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a very similar issue with Ubuntu 12.04. I just couldn't seem to login with root & no password. I set the AllowNoPassword setting to TRUE in the config. Later I found out that I was editing the wrong config.inc.php file to add the AllowNoPassword setting.

```
Edit:
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
Not:
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

I believe the first is the debian local config file, which will override the usr version.

Answer (score 0):

well , hello
first download the phpmyadmin from here :
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

then extract the downloaded (rar,zip) to :
{INSTILLATION_PATH }\laragon\etc\apps
rename the folder to phpmyadmin .

now go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin

and your there :) .

if you want to login to the phpmyadmin you need to search in the phpmyadmin folder for a file called config.sample.inc and duplicate it and rename it to config.inc open the file and search for :
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
and set it to true : $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
save the file and DONE you can login using username of : root

Answer (score 0):

It seemed logical to me to keep things at the simplest level possible:

```
mysql -u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Thus phpmyadmin user which was created during the installation manages everything, including create databases.